# Android initializatoin of class fields not done

Tags: java, android, initialization, ondestroy

Struggled with an appropriate title on this one.   I've encountered and odd/baffling situation which only came to light as I sometimes initialize fields.

In this case, I had a boolean which I initialized to false (I know, redundant... but...)

the app runs fine and prior to exit my boolean is set to true.  I watch the log cat to see that onDestroy() has been called.

I then restart the app.

My boolean, whose value I now log in onCreate(), is true.

WTF?

I noted that the activity started with a new PID. And yet, it is bypassing field initializations.  Mind you, I have some which are not redundant.  So what is going on here?

I then force stopped the app from the settings menu on the device.  Restarting the app now shows all as expected, boolean = false.

So is onDestroy() not a reliable/real termination? I don't recall ever reading anything like that.

This is not my app but is an example of the situation:

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity {
/**
 * Called when the activity is first created.
 */
private static boolean b = false;
private static int i = 1;
private static final String TAG = "junk app";
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    Log.i(TAG, "==================================================================");
    if(b) Log.i(TAG,"boolean is true");
    if(!b) Log.i(TAG,"boolean is false");
    Log.i(TAG,"The value of i is"+i);
    i++;
    b=!b;

    foo();
}
public void foo() {
    finish();
}

@Override
public void onResume() {
    Log.i(TAG,"onResume");
    super.onResume();
}

@Override
public void onStop() {
    Log.i(TAG,"onStop");
    super.onStop();
}
@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    Log.i(TAG,"onDestroy");
    super.onDestroy();
}
```

}

Run this app on a device and watch your logcat.  onDestroy() is called.  Now start the app again from its icon.   i is incremented and b becomes !b.

IDK but my (naive) expectation is that if an app is destroyed, if it is restarted it starts fresh and all initializations, etc are done again.

Comment: Please post a *simple* example of code that recreates this issue.

Comment: Are you setting your boolean to `false` in `onDestroy()`?

Comment: No. The boolean is set to false in the intialization section, ie right after public class MainActivity.  It is later set to true.  The app is eventually destroyed.  If you then restart the app the boolean is still true

Comment: "I noted that the activity started with a new PID..." Are you sure about this? Any proof?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Statics are statics -- they are global to the process.  So their value
>   will last for the lifetime of the process, which is usually much
>   longer than an individual activity instance.

Source: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/android-developers/PZXbCXliRbo

Comment: Wow that really is quite interesting.. and I've just seen it in action too.. I left the desk for 45 minutes and restarted the test above and it came with a new PID and all the statics were initialized fresh.     I'll keep this in mind in the future and now go back thru my code to see what should be changed.  Thanks for the quick and accurate reply

Comment: Anytime! I actually had the same understanding as you, so I'm glad I learned something from this as well. I try to avoid static variables whenever I can, but occasionally I _need_ them and it's much better to at least have an idea of what is happening behind the scenes.